# Deserialize JSON into objects containing custom C# objects

Tags: json.net

Having trouble deserializing some JSON into custom C# objects. I thought that if I construct a class that looks like the JSON, it'll know which customs object classes to use (Display and Range), but obviously i'm doing something wrong. After the deserialize call, both Display and Range are null.
Guessing I'm missing some wrappers, but not sure how to set those up.

Here's the JSON of only one "param":

```
{
 "Params": [
     { // This is a "Param" object
       "Type": "myType",
        "EnumCode": "ZZZ",
        "Display": {
            "Name": "myName",
            "Description": "myDescription"
          }
         "Range": {
             "Default": "1",
              "Values": [
                  "1",
                   "2"
               ]
          }
      }
   ]
}
```

And these are my classes:

```
public class Display
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Range
{
    public string Default { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
public class Param
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string EnumCode { get; set; }
    public Display UIDisplay { get; set; }
    public Range RangeValues { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to deserialize the JSON using this wrapper:

```
public class ParamsJSON
{
    public List<Param> Params;
}
```

Like so:

```
var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TuneParameterJSON>(File.ReadAllText(paramsFilePath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, my bad. Renaming the classes to CDisplay and CRange was what I was missing.

```
public class Param
{
    ...
    public CDisplay Display { get; set; }
    public CRange Range { get; set; 
}
```